# Probability that at least 50 students out of 400 will pass an exam?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Question from [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com.hk/Interview/Chance-that-a-student-passes-the-test-is-10-What-is-the-chance-that-out-of-400-students-AT-LEAST-50-pass-the-test-Check-QTN_2329434.htm):

> Chance that a student passes the test is 10%. What is the chance that
> out of 400 students AT LEAST 50 pass the test? Check the closest
> answer: The offered answers were 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 25%.

Let $X_i=1$ if $i'$th student passes the test and $X_i=0$ if fails. Also, let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{400}X_i$. Then $X$ form a binomial distribution with $p=0.1$ and $n=400$. Thus,

$\Pr(X\geq50)=1-\Pr(X\leq49)=1-\sum_{x=0}^{49}\binom{400}{x}0.1^x0.9^{400-x}.$

But I don't know if there is any easy way to approximate the above value.

Also, maybe one way is to use mean and variance: $E[X]=np=40$ and $\mathrm{var}(X)=np(1-p)=36$?

Comment: You could use the normal approximation. Just take the normal distribution with the same mean and variance. Use the continuity correction.

Comment: @lulu not sure if it will solve the problem, as I know CDF of normal distribution is not easy to compute either.

Comment: "At least 50" is the complement of "less than 50" so it might be simplest to calculate the probability of "less than  50" and subtract from 1. If the probability of any student passing is 10%, then the probability of no student passing is .9^400, the probability of one student passing is 400(.9^399)(.1), etc.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey your answer is exactly as my answer. But I don't think we can compute this value easily without software.

Comment: You are looking for $P(X≤49.5)$ and since we have mean $40$ and $\sigma =6$ we are interested in $P(X≤1.58\sigma)$ (more or less).  Even without machine help you might know the one sided $95\%$ rule...in any case, all you need to do is to rule out the answers $≥10\%$.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interview question so I imagine no calculating device was allowed. It can be done without external aid if you have a background in elementary Statistics.

We have to estimate $P(X\ge 50)$ where $X$ is binomial with $n=400$ and $p=0.1$. 
Using the normal approximation to the Binomial distribution and a continuity correction, as suggested in the comments. we have to find $P(Y\ge 49.5)$ where $Y$ is normal with mean $40$ and variance $36$.
This is $P(Z> \frac{49.5-40}{6}) = P(Z>1.6)$ where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution. 
This probability is approximately $5\%$. (The actual value giving $5\%$ is around $1.65$  which any statistician should know).